# Extra horizontal lines in google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Suddenly I have some strange horizontal lines in Google Maps. Please see: http://hippo.ornl.gov/10secdownload/. It was working fine and appeared about a couple of weeks ago. I drew those layers using kml files and I checked them in Google Earth and Google My Maps where they work fine. I can provide kml files if needed.

Comment: It would be helpful to show some relevant code (kml or other); it would help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Have you noticed this issue on any other KML files?